# Getting input from stdin in a Cocoa command-line app's sub process

Tags: swift, shell, cocoa, foundation

I have a command-line app `A`, and in `A` I execute an executable script `B`, in `B` I'm expecting an input from stdin.

I wrote a demo, implementing `A` in Swift, using `Foundation`'s `Process` api, finding that `B`, no matter implemented in whatever language, cannot get user input from stdin.

Code:

```
// `A`'s main.swift
import Foundation
let process = Process()
process.launchPath = PATH_TO_SCRIPT_B
process.launch()
process.waitUntilExit()

// `B`
#!/usr/bin/swift 
print("intpu something")
let input = readLine()
print("input: \(input)")
```

I did not set the `process`'s input since according to the doc:

> If this method isn’t used, the standard input is inherited from the process that created the receiver.

---

UPDATE:

`A` is an executable package created using Swift Package Manager. I used `swift package generate-xcodeproj` to generate an Xcode project file. I confirmed that if I run the executable built using `swift build` or `xcodebuild` in a shell, the problem with getting input from stdin from `B` arose. However if I run it directly inside Xcode, by pressing `command + R` inside Xcode, then it worked. So if I understand the difference between running an executable in a shell and Xcode, I can probably make everything work.

Comment: Are you allowed to pass an input from  `shell` built-ins from command-line?

Comment: @Inian I'm not familiar with the concept you mention (which is related to shell itself?), but I did wrote `A` in Ruby and it works as I expected. If you think this might be related then could you provide some more information?

Answer (score 1):

```
func task() {
  print("input here")
  let x = input()
  print ("inputed:" + x)
}

func input() -> String {
  let keyboard = FileHandle.standardInput
  let inputData = keyboard.availableData
  let strData = String(data: inputData, encoding: .utf8)!

  let string = strData.trimmingCharacters(in: .newlines)
  return string
}

task()
```

Hope it helps